# Unable to resolve class inside static method

Tags: groovy, groovy-eclipse, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a groovy class "Utils.groovy" which contains the method "makeHttpCall()".
This is a summarized version of the method:

```
static String makeHTTPCall() {
    ...
    request.setHeader(javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader)
    ...
}
```

The compiler complains:

> Groovy:Apparent variable 'javax' was found in a static scope but
>   doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class.

If I make the method non-static though, it will stop complaining;

```
String makeHTTPCall() {
    ...
    request.setHeader(javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader)
    ...
}
```

this way it doesn't complain. Why does the compiler complain about this?

Note that the method runs with no problems; it is run as part of a Jenkins shared library.

Thanks!

EDIT: Using 
`import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders` gives

> Groovy:unable to resolve class javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders

So that class is not resolvable by the compiler, but it is when run inside Jenkins.

Comment: use `import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders`

Comment: Did you yet try to use a static import, like ‘’’import static javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION’’’?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the library that provides "javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders" to your project's buildpath.  Alternatively, you can use an @Grab to your class/script.  This is probably not what you want in this case since Jenkins is providing that dependency at runtime.